# Using CRTP to import function overloads

Tags: c++, overloading, crtp

I am trying the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T t;
};

template <class Derived>
struct wrapper_support
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator ()(Wrapper<T> const & w) const
    {
        return static_cast<Derived const &>(*this)(w.t);
    }
};

struct functor : wrapper_support<functor>
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator ()(T t) const {return t == 42;}
};

void test()
{
    functor f;
    std::cout << f(Wrapper<int>{42}) << std::endl;
}
```

but it fails to compile: when resolving the call to `f.operator ()`, only `functor::operator ()(T) const` is considered because it is hiding `wrapper_support`'s `operator ()`.

Changing the code to

```
struct functor : wrapper_support<functor>
{
    using wrapper_support<functor>::operator ();
    template <typename T>
    bool operator ()(T t) const {return t == 42;}
};
```

resolves the problem but I wish I could avoid adding the `using` directive.

*Edit:*

I finally implemented it using a macro:

```
#define WRAPPER_SUPPORT                           \
    template <typename T>                         \
    bool operator ()(Wrapper<T> const & w) const  \
    {                                             \
        return (*this)(w.t);                      \
    }

struct functor
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator ()(T t) const {return t == 42;}

    WRAPPER_SUPPORT
};
```

But then I faced a new problem. In order to be more generic, I changed the macro to the following:

```
#define WRAPPER_SUPPORT                           \
    template <typename T>                         \
    auto operator ()(Wrapper<T> const & w) const  \
        -> decltype((*this)(w.t))                 \
    {                                             \
        return (*this)(w.t);                      \
    }
```

and it fell again into the same problem with Visual C++ 2013.

I tried the code on Ideone (in C++, not C++14) and it worked fine.

Is this a Visual C++ limitation and is there a workaround?